# Dump network traffic of guest VM to host filesystem via serial console or vsock?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a VM which uses a VPN for connectivity and I need to dump the traffic of the VPN interface to some pcap file on the host. The VM is fairly stripped down but I can run tcpdump. I can't however use something like NFS and shared filesystems. 
I can attach to the serial console of the VM and of course run tcpdump through it. But how can I get the pcap on the host? Maybe I can also do it via vsocks.
Anyone knows  how to  do this  in a practical way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File transfer, perhaps scp. "Removable" media.

Upload to a packet capture appliance or SaS service (like CloudShark).

SPAN or TAP somewhere on its path, and strip out the encapsulated traffic.

Edit: encapsulate at the host and mirror it somewhere else. Recent Linux can do ERSPAN.

Edit 2: For the vsock implementation you want, go find a guest to host file transfer program using AF_VSOCK. The VM sockets concept is new enough where this probably means compiling someone's code. Like the go implementation at [mdlayher/vsock](https://github.com/mdlayher/vsock) which has a file transfer demo program vscp. Up to you whether you think bypassing the IP stack is worth the effort of hacking on it. And if you want something without a lot of production use yet.

Comment: Sadly none of this is an option. It needs to be live, so removable media does not work. Also the VM is fairly isolated so the scp command wont work either. With tapping I only get the encrypted traffic which I already can get but I need the traffic arriving directly on the tunnel interface.

Comment: Re edit: Sure, but the question is how do I get the traffic to the host or some file on the host in the first place. The possibilities are limited to serial and vsock.

Comment: Regarding AF_VSOCK, what have you tried? My latest edit links to some example code.

Comment: I tried nothing because there is not much you can find. Thanks for digging up the vscp command though. vsock is fairly new. There is a reason why things like vsock get implemented, or the upcoming virtiofs. You can't always use the ip stack for whatever reasons.